# How to iterate and modify over a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array that I would like to iterate over and modify the array itself, through inserts or deletions.

```
for idx, ele in enumerate(np.nditer(array)):
  if idx + 1 < array.shape[0] and ele > array[idx+1]:
    array = np.delete(array, idx+1)
  print(ele)
```

Given [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] I want the loop to print out 5 3 1 because 4 and 2 are smaller than their previous elements. But because python creates an iterator based on the first instance of `array` so it prints 5 4 3 2 1. I want to know if I can get

Generally speaking I want the iterator to be modified if I modify the array within the body of my loop.

Comment: Usually objects such as function, classes.. used from the standard library, or other third-party library should behave as the docs says. So you do not have to check their behavior in your code.

Comment: But you may mean something else, so please add more details to your question if so.

Comment: Your loop seems to do what you want - at least for that input. It isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: I've added some more information. Is it clearer?

Comment: If you are changing `array` along the way, it may be better to use a `while` loop rather than `for`. And avoid `nditer` unless you really need some special feature.

Comment: @hpaulj Will while loops reevaluate the loop condition on every iteration?

Comment: "python creates iterable object by evaluating the array the first time." "the loop reevaluate the object" - sorry, this is word salad to me. We need an example with initial array, expected output and actual output.

Comment: You can try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022811/11610186

Comment: @actual_panda I removed the example I had before because all the answers were trying to solve the example rather than the general problem. I added it back.

Comment: @actual_panda. Thanks for the term "word salad".

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski but iterating over the original will not reflect changes I make in the copy which is what I want.

Comment: The final array when running your new code is `array([1, 2, 4, 5])`. If you don't want `ele` to print if `ele == 3`, use an `else` block? https://pastebin.com/17zvAWaA

Comment: @actual_panda I'm not referring to this specific example. As many others have pointed out and as I mentioned in edits to my post I could solve this specific problem by using boolean indexing. Generally speaking, if I change an array I am iterating over during the loop, I want following iterations of my array to reflect that change.

Comment: @vnal That's how it's working already.

Comment: @actual_panda I'm not talking about the output array. I'm talking about the print output.

Comment: This has nothing to do with how Python builds iterators then. You assign `ele = 3`. Then you `print(ele)`. There is no way to make it print something else without reassigning the name.

Comment: @actual_panda Pretend it's a linked list or something. Honestly the specifics of "ele is already assigned a value" aren't really important here because this specific example isn't as complex as the actual problem I'm dealing with. I just want to know if there is a way to change a data structure I'm iterating over  in a for loop and have that change be reflected in later iterations of that same for loop.

Comment: Again, that's already how iteration works in Python. You can mutate the object you are iterating over in the loop body, and that mutation will apply to future iterations.

Comment: (Note that in your example, you are not mutating anything. `np.delete` returns a new array. Then you rebind the name `array` to the return value.)

Comment: @actual_panda If that's how iterators work then that's what I want to do. I want to modify the same array but I can only find ways to delete and assign to a copy. I just posted another example.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mutate the length of a numpy array, because numpy assigns the required memory for an array upon its creation.

With

```
array = np.delete(array, idx+1)
```

You are creating a new array on the right hand side of the `=` and reassign the name `array`.

The return value for `enumerate(np.nditer(array))` has already been created at that point and won't recognize that the name `array` has been rebound.

In principle, you can iterate over a sequence and mutate its length at the same time (generally not a good idea). The object just needs to have methods that let you mutate its length (like lists, for example).

Consider:

```
>>> l = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]                                                         
>>> for idx, ele in enumerate(l): 
...:     if ele == 3: 
...:         l.pop(idx) # mutates l 
...:     print(ele) 
...:                                                                            
5
4
3
1
>>> l                                                                           
[5, 4, 2, 1]
```

Notice that

1. `l` is mutated.
2. The loop does not print `2` because popping an element reduces the indexes of all the remaining elements by one. Now `l[2] == 2`, but index `2` has already been visited by the iterator, so the next print-call prints `l[3]` which is 1.

This proves that mutations to `l` have effect on subsequent iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over an array, you can use *where* method to find
indices of elements meeting some condition.

Then to **delete** the selected element (or elements), you can use
*delete* method, passing the source array, and a list of indices.
Then save the result, e.g. under the same variable.

To **add** an element, you can use *append* or *insert* methods
(for details see *Numpy* documentation).

I have also found a SO post concerning how to loop and delete over an array.
See [Deleting elements from numpy array with iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914905/deleting-elements-from-numpy-array-with-iteration)

Comment: Please read my post carefully. I'm not referring to that specific example.